# Pushing a children to "this" will also push it in the child's childrens... (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, ecmascript-5

I have some entity/component code in javascript. It's mostly done but I am hitting this really weird problem. My entities have a childrens array in which I push the childrens, and some other array (componentsDictionary, will be renamed don't worry, it used to be a dict) for it's components.

Now when I am calling this.childrens.push(obj), it's pushing the object both in this.childrens and inside obj.childrens... Causing me an infinite loop when I will update my render tree.

Probably a problem with the really weird handling of closures in JS...

Here is the problematic code :

```
Entity.prototype = {
    childrens : [],
    componentsDictionary : [],
    sharedAttributes : {}, // This data is shared for all components
    debugName : "Entity Default Name",
    bubblee : null,

    Add : function(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Entity) {
            alert(obj.debugName); // alerts "entity 0"
            alert(this.debugName); // alerts "root"

            alert(obj.childrens.length); // "alerts 0"
            this.childrens.push(obj);
            alert(obj.childrens.length); // "alerts 1"
            // how the f... !%!??!%11?
        }
        else if (obj instanceof IComponent) {
            this.componentsDictionary[obj.type].push(obj);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exceptions.IllegalAction("Attempted to add something else than an entity or a component to an entity.");
        }
    },
```

Thanks alot!

Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've put the "childrens" array on the prototype object, it's shared by every instance of "Entity".  There's only one array, in other words.

If you want a separate array per instance, remove it from the prototype and add

```
this.childrens = [];
```

to the "Entity" constructor.

Comment: I thought Scope.prototype.var would be an attribute and Scope.var would be a static attribute... seems like I need to check my ecmascript fundamentals.

Comment: @NGauthier the prototype properties are all shared - properties that are functions are not treated differently than properties that aren't.

Comment: You are totally right, gotta refactor some other stuff, well thanks, will select your awnser asap